# mercadoenvios fuera?

Tags: mercadolibre

Me gustaría probar una cuenta de vendedor de mercadopago, pero me obliga a usar mercadoenvios.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para tener una cuenta de vendedor sin mercadoenvios?

Comment: Hola Alexa, Bienvenido(a). Te sugeriria que hagas el tour, http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, ya que tu pregunta no parece estar relacionada a desarrollar sistemas. Saludos.

Comment: Una cuenta en un sistema así es un servicio, y si se trata de condiciones de un servicio, solo un representante legal te puede dar una respuesta definitiva. Mesa ayuda del servicio te deberían dar una respuesta a tu duda.